# Remove component after animation played in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using conditional rendering to render a specific button, if the state.show = true.
The problem is, that, if show is not true, the anim is played, but the component is not removed (because the anim doesn't remove the component, it's just animating it.)

i'm using **Material ui**, **aphrodite**, **react-magic**

there's my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import {StyleSheet, css} from 'aphrodite'
import { swap, vanishOut } from 'react-magic'
import vanishIn from 'react-magic/lib/bling/vanishIn';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  magic: {
      animationName: vanishIn,
      animationDuration: '2s'
  },
  magicOut: {
    animationName: vanishOut,
    animationDuration: '2s'
  }
});


class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {show: true};
}


FalseState(){
  this.setState({show:false});
}



  render() {

    const show = this.state.show
    let buttonStart;

    if(show===true){
      buttonStart =
      <div className={css(styles.magic)}>
      <Button className="start" variant="raised" onClick={() => this.FalseState()}>Button</Button>
    </div>;

    } else {
      buttonStart =
      <div className={css(styles.magicOut)}>
      <Button className="start" variant="raised" >Button</Button>
    </div>;
    }

  return (
  <div className="App">
    {buttonStart}
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use another state variable to trigger a **unmount** of the component after the animation is over - using **setTimeout**.

Hope this helps :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { StyleSheet, css } from 'aphrodite';
import { swap, vanishOut } from 'react-magic';
import vanishIn from 'react-magic/lib/bling/vanishIn';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    magic: {
        animationName: vanishIn,
        animationDuration: '2s'
    },
    magicOut: {
        animationName: vanishOut,
        animationDuration: '2s'
    }
});

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { show: true, unMount: false };
    }

    FalseState() {
        this.setState({ show: false }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({ unMount: true });
            }, 2000);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const show = this.state.show;
        let buttonStart;

        if (this.state.unMount) {
            return null;
        }

        if (show === true) {
            buttonStart = (
                <div className={css(styles.magic)}>
                    <Button className="start" variant="raised" onClick={() => this.FalseState()}>
                        Button
                    </Button>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            buttonStart = (
                <div className={css(styles.magicOut)}>
                    <Button className="start" variant="raised">
                        Button
                    </Button>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return <div className="App">{buttonStart}</div>;
    }
}

export default App;
```